# ANOVA type III strange results

Tags: anova

I am performing some simulations for a power analysis but, I am finding some strange results.

In a scenario of a two-way ANOVA (5*5) where I check a relevant interaction (One level of Factor B different in a level of Factor A), running an ANOVA type III will yield a significant result for Factor B and the interaction A:B, even without a clear specific effect of Factor B.

Here is a practical example:

```
library(car)

set.seed(1234)

Grps_A<-5
Grps_B<-5
j<-10
stdev<-1
avs<-c(
  c(1,0,0,0,0)+6,
  c(0,0,0,0,0)+6,
  c(0,0,0,0,0)+6,
  c(0,0,0,0,0)+6,
  c(0,0,0,0,0)+6)

NamesGrps_A<-paste0("A_G",1:Grps_A)
NamesGrps_B<-paste0("B_G",1:Grps_B)

cont<-c()
for (i in 1:length(avs)) {
  cont<-c(cont,rnorm(j,mean=avs[i],sd=stdev))
}

FactorA<-rep(NamesGrps_A,each=j*Grps_B)
FactorB<-rep(rep(NamesGrps_B,each=j),times=Grps_A)

df<-data.frame(FactorA,FactorB,cont)


ml1<-lm(cont ~ FactorA * FactorB, data = df)
summary(aov(ml1))
Anova(ml1,type=2)
Anova(ml1,type=3,contrasts=list(FactorA='contr.sum', FactorB ='contr.sum'))
```

The results of ANOVA type I and II make sense to me but, the type III is the one I am baffled with:

```
> summary(aov(ml1))
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
FactorA           4   6.29  1.5716   1.623 0.1693  
FactorB           4   7.00  1.7499   1.807 0.1283  
FactorA:FactorB  16  28.64  1.7897   1.849 0.0265 *
Residuals       225 217.84  0.9682                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> Anova(ml1,type=2)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: cont
                 Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)  
FactorA           6.286   4  1.6232 0.1693  
FactorB           7.000   4  1.8074 0.1283  
FactorA:FactorB  28.635  16  1.8485 0.0265 *
Residuals       217.844 225                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> Anova(ml1,type=3,contrasts=list(FactorA='contr.sum', FactorB ='contr.sum'))
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: cont
                Sum Sq  Df  F value  Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)     437.83   1 452.2081 < 2e-16 ***
FactorA           6.60   4   1.7050 0.14980    
FactorB          11.84   4   3.0564 0.01767 *  
FactorA:FactorB  28.64  16   1.8485 0.02650 *  
Residuals       217.84 225                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am checking the three types when running different scenarions (factor A varying, factor B varying, now the interaction) to see what happens in said power analysis.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you include a seed with any random number generation, the results won't be the same for anyone else (or you) otherwise. Also, I have no idea which package the `tidy` or `Anova` functions come from?

Comment: Thanks @PBulls! Rewrite the code with the suggestions made

Answer (score 1):

I was re-reading several posts online and the documentation for the `car::Anova` function and I was setting the contrasts **outside of the lm**, thus causing the error. After correcting that, the results for ANOVA type I, II and III, *in a scenario of balanced data*, yield the same result.

I reiterate the warning I found in the function documentation, highlighting an important recommendation:

"Be careful of type-III tests: For a traditional multifactor ANOVA model with interactions, for example, these tests will normally only be sensible when using contrasts that, for different terms, are orthogonal in the row-basis of the model, such as those produced by contr.sum, contr.poly, or contr.helmert, but not by the default contr.treatment. In a model that contains factors, numeric covariates, and interactions, main-effect tests for factors will be for differences over the origin. In contrast (pun intended), type-II tests are invariant with respect to (full-rank) contrast coding. **If you don't understand this issue, then you probably shouldn't use Anova for type-III tests.**"